# Left Join repeat for each employee

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, left-join

I am using Oracle 11g and SQL Developer 16.260.

TABLE 1 - EMPLOYEE

```
ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
1   CHRIS       PETERS
2   MICHELLE    ANDREWS
3   ANDY        JONES
```

TABLE 2 – SKILLS

```
ID  SKILL
1   WRITING
2   READING
3   COMPUTERS
4   EXCEL
5   TYPING 
6   MS WORD
```

TABLE 3 – EMPLOYEE_SKILLS

```
ID  EMPLOYEE_ID SKILLS_ID
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   1           4
4   2           1
5   2           2
6   2           3
7   2           6
8   3           1
9   3           6
10  3           5
```

I am looking for a query that will give me the following results

```
EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME  SKILL      COMPLETE
CHRIS               PETERS              WRITING    Complete
CHRIS               PETERS              READING    Complete
CHRIS               PETERS              COMPUTERS  Incomplete
CHRIS               PETERS              EXCEL      Complete
CHRIS               PETERS              TYPING     Incomplete
CHRIS               PETERS              MS WORD    Incomplete
MICHELLE            ANDREWS             WRITING    Complete
MICHELLE            ANDREWS             READING    Complete
MICHELLE            ANDREWS             COMPUTERS  Complete
MICHELLE            ANDREWS             EXCEL      Incomplete
MICHELLE            ANDREWS             TYPING     Incomplete
MICHELLE            ANDREWS             MS WORD    Complete
ANDY                JONES               WRITING    Complete
ANDY                JONES               READING    Incomplete
ANDY                JONES               COMPUTERS  Incomplete
ANDY                JONES               EXCEL      Incomplete
ANDY                JONES               TYPING     Complete
ANDY                JONES               MS WORD    Complete
```

I have tried and other variations of

```
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, S.SKILL, CASE ES.SKILLS_ID IS NULL THEN        'Incomplete' ELSE 'COMPLETE' END
FROM EMPLOYEE E, EMPLOYEE_SKILLS ES
LEFT JOIN SKILLS S ON S.ID = ES.SKILLS_ID
WHERE EMPLOYEE.ID=EMPLOYEE_SKILLS.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

I can not seem to have the SKILLS repeat for each employee.

Comment: Switch to explicit `JOIN` everywhere! Mixing OUTER JOIN with old, comma separated, implicit join is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, S.SKILL,
       (CASE ES.SKILLS_ID IS NULL THEN 'Incomplete' ELSE 'Complete' END)
FROM EMPLOYEE E CROSS JOIN
     SKILLS S LEFT JOIN
     EMPLOYEE_SKILLS ES 
     ON S.ID = ES.SKILLS_ID AND E.ID = ES.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Comment: I could hug you! Thank you so very much, you are awesome!

Comment: Again! Thank you!